# PHP system() howto export PATH

Tags: php, export, system

I want to change the default system $PATH var for the period of php script execution, but it for some reason fails.

Im trying the following:

```
<?php
$lastline = system('export PATH=$PATH:/customBin;',$return) OR die("why do i die all the time");
echo $lastline;
?>
```

But it obviously dies all the time. (tried on both RHEL & Debian linux distros, php version 5.3.xx, other system commands work fine (cat, ls, etc) neither of these work: `export PATH=$PATH:/customBin;` OR `export PATH=$PATH:/customBin:` OR `export PATH=/customBin`, all of these work in the shell tho..)

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

EDIT: Above code is wrong, solution is to use `putenv('PATH=$PATH:/customBin');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have better luck using [putenv](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) to change environment variables from PHP. Just fetch the current value with [getenv](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), add whatever you like and finally call putenv to alter the value.

Comment: +1. This is the best solution. Playing with `system` is a hack.

Answer (score 3):

System's `return value` (*not* the return parameter) is the last line of the command(s)' output or boolean `FALSE` if it fails. In your case it probably succeeded (you have `int 0` in your $return variable for a successful exit) and returned nothing (an empty string perhaps) which evaluates to false in your or statement and the die gets executed. If you want to check for a successful export, try

```
system('export PATH=$PATH:/customBin;', $return);
$return === 0 OR die('...');
```

or if you want to use system's failure handler:

```
(system('export PATH=$PATH:/customBin;') !== FALSE) or die('...');
```

Haven't tested this, your results may vary.

Comment: thanks, but still doesnt work :( I changed the test to simpler test:
`system('export PATH=$PATH:/customBin;', $return);

echo system('echo $PATH');`

@wimvds ive tried `/home/myuser/customBin` - this didnt work either -(

and it returns standard: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

Comment: As far as I know exporting the variable changes it only for the current session. So if you call `system` twice, the second session might not be aware of it anymore (has the original value).

Comment: Have you tried `system('export PATH=$PATH:/customBin;echo $PATH;', $return);`?

Comment: @ Denis 'Alpheus' Čahuk
Thank you! this works: `system('export PATH=$PATH:/customBin; echo $PATH;', $return);`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with `system` is creating a new shell environment, setting the PATH in that, then leaving it.

In addition, your check for success is broken. The call returns an empty string, which then fails your conditional check.

As far as I am aware, you can't manipulate the environment that invoked *php*.

Comment: yah, I got this point now. didnt think about return value being empty when was trying to do a check. the answer above is working tho. thanks